# Why Doesn't preg_match return data? Design Decision?

Tags: php, preg-match

I was wondering if there was a programmatic reason why php developers chose to not have `preg_match` return data.

I'm mainly wondering if it is faster to reference variables that don't exist instead of returning values?

Or is this just one of those "its just the way the function was implemented" issues?

I appreciate your time, ty.

Comment: It is frequently (maybe even most often?) used simply to verify a match. No sense in eating additional memory capturing values that won't be used later unless you explicitly intend to use them.  Interesting question I think -- there's at least one PHP dev I can think of lurking around SO, so hopefully you can get some insider opinion.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that this belongs on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) because it is not [a specific programming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) but a theoretical question. It is a good one though... I mean, if you just returned an array of matches, it could still be evaluated as a boolean (`array() == FALSE`) and you could easily just `count()` it if you wanted the number of matches.

Comment: Actually, looking at [this document](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt), there are considerably more C-API function calls involved if you want to extract the matched strings, whereas if all you want is to know *if* there is a match then there are only a couple. So I'd guess it's an efficiency decision.

Comment: The intent of the `preg_match()` method is to allow the programmer to determine *existence* of a substring matching a regular expression. As with most functions, the community *likely* decided that a simple `boolean` return value was found to be insufficient, when programmers realized they also wanted to see *which* substrings matched the regular expression, so the `&$matches` parameter was added, allowing both a `boolean` return value and an `array` to be "returned" in the form of "changing the value by modifying an array passed by reference." Notice how `&matches` isn't a required parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it this way avoids needless string buffer copying when the actual captured substrings are not used; depending on the string sizes, this can be a substantial waste of resources.

When the `$matches` argument is not passed, PHP can determine whether to allocate resources for it or not. The same can't be done for the return value, because `preg_match()` is typically used inside a condition which needs to evaluate it.